What is the pullback in the category of differential manifolds?
I have learned that the pullback exists in the category of topology spaces. I am wondering if the pullback exists in the category of differential manifolds.
In fact I want to convince myself the following: let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth map between differential manifolds, let $\pi:E\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth vector bundle. I have already learned that $f^*(E)$ is a vector bundle, but how to define the differential structure on $f^*(E)$, such that $\pi': f^*(E)\rightarrow X$ is a smooth vector bundle?
Edit: Here is what I have tried:
Let $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}$ be a bundle atlas of $E$. We define:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \overline{\varphi_\alpha}: (f^*E)_{f^{-1}(U_\alpha)}&\rightarrow f^{-1}(U_\alpha)\times \mathbb{R}^n\\
     (x,e)&\mapsto (x,\mathrm{pr}_2\circ \varphi_\alpha(e))
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
I can show that $\overline{\varphi_\alpha}$ gives the local trivialization. So probably we can compose it with a chart in $X$ to get a smooth atlas in $f^*E$ (I am not sure)?
But this kind of construction relies on the vector bundle structure of $E\rightarrow Y$. I am also curious that in general when $f:X\rightarrow Z$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ are just smooth maps btw differential manifolds, can we define the pullback $f^*Y=X\times_Z Y$ and how? (I know the top. structure, but cannot find out a natural way to define the diff. structure)
Any hints, reference are welcomed. THANKS!

What did you try? Where did you get stuck? (If you understood the proof that pull-back defines a vector bundle, the construction of a smooth atlas is quite obvious.)

@MoisheKohan  Thanks for you comment. Here is what I have tried:
Let ${(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)}$ be a bundle atlas of $E$.  I can show that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\overline{\varphi_\alpha}: (f^*E){f^{-1}(U\alpha)}&\rightarrow f^{-1}(U_\alpha)\times \mathbb{R}^n\
(x,e)&\mapsto (x,\mathrm{pr}2\circ \varphi\alpha(e))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
gives the local trivialization. So probably this gives the desired smooth atlas by intersecting with a chart in $X$? :)

please add this to the original question, instead of hiding it in the comments.

The trick is to think in terms of sections and not trivializations. The space of sections of $f^*E$ is the $C^\infty(X)$-module generated by the pullback by $f$ of sections of $E$ over $Y$. Another way is to observe that there is a equivalence between local trivializations and local frames. Here, the vector bundle structure of $f^*E$ can be specified by saying that the pullback by $f$ of any local frame of $E$ is defined to be a local section of $f^*E$. Using this, it is obvious that the transition maps are smooth. I think the trivialization you have written above is equivalent to this.
